# Very slow stack frames in static library

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management

I'm writing the memory manager for my https://github.com/mikelsv/msvcore2 library. Using intercept functions: `malloc()`, `realloc()`, `free()`.

Problem: get stack frames in my_malloc() called in openssl library(or any else).
Example stack: `RSA_generate_key() -> BN_new -> CRYPTO_zalloc -> my_malloc()`.

Solutions.

1. `CaptureStackBackTrace()`. Returned short stack, only "CRYPTO_zalloc". Not good.
2. Variants of __asm { mov prev, ebp } not work for me.
3. `StackWalk()` - Work. But, very slow.

How to get stack frames in static library, quickly as possible?

I'm use MSVS 2010 & 2012.

**Oh, wait!** Need only 4th frame in my `GetStackTypeInfo()`. Fast fix: `if(CaptureStackBackTrace() have 4th frame){ use it; } else StackWalk()`. It's better working version. But, also slow.

My memory manager https://github.com/mikelsv/memman. Mem control: https://github.com/mikelsv/msvcore2/blob/master/define/memcon.h , get stack info: GetStackTypeInfo() - https://github.com/mikelsv/msvcore2/blob/master/define/memcon.h#L738 .

Comment: in general case impossible get stack frames on x86 without symbols information in pdb. because not all functions use `ebp` frames

Comment: You have explained your solution, but never talked about the problem you are trying to solve. If you stated your problem instead, you might get better feedback. From the sounds of it, your proposed solution is neither practical nor reliable.

Comment: @IInspectable problem: search for memory leaks. I'm interested to complete my version, he is good, but has a problems.

Comment: Why do you assume, that walking the stack would help to search for memory leaks? And how do you propose to deal with optimized code (e.g. omitted frame pointers)? Some code is inherently platform specific. Don't impose Linux restrictions into your Windows code, when Windows offers a commercial grade debug heap out-of-the-box.

Comment: @IInspectable Walking the stack need for get stack trace information and uniq id. This makes it possible to count the call malloc / free for each stack trace. Program output: http://pastebin.com/PDwNfqFS Optimized code? Use memman in Debug only.

Comment: @IInspectable Install MSVS 2015. Memory debugger gives too much information. My project seems convenient. It also works in real time. And it does not take an awful lot of disk space as the MSVS memory profiler.

Comment: I'm not talking about Visual Studio's memory profiler. I'm talking about the debug functionality built into the OS, accessible e.g. through the [CRT Debug Heap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx) implementation. Walking the stack allows you to count memory allocations that are in flight at any given moment. This is not generally useful information, and certainly won't produce reliable data for leak detection.