# Get unique id based on stack trace. Fast

Tags: c++, windows, stack

This question based on [Very slow stack frames in static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415497/very-slow-stack-frames-in-static-library) .

How get unique identify for this stack trace? It need for my memory manager: https://github.com/mikelsv/memman.

The problem with the interception of calls from the openssl library (and perhaps others libraries).

**Problems:**

1. Get unique id for prevous stack frame. Need for: `Type *tel = FindType(prevous stack name); tel->allocate count ++;`
2. Get unique id for all stack frames. Need for: `Stack *sel = FindStack(uniq stack id); sel->allocate count ++;`

**The current solution:**

Use `CaptureStackBackTrace()` else `StackWalk()`. But, `CaptureStackBackTrace()` - don't show all stack frames, `StackWalk()` - very slowly.

How do I get faster unique identifier stack?

**Current code:** https://github.com/mikelsv/msvcore2/blob/master/define/memcon.h

1. See `GetStackTypeInfo();`
2. See `StackCrc();` - fast, but count short stack. Example: First stack frame `CRYPTO_realloc`. This problem: only one unique id for `"any calls" -> CRYPTO_realloc()`.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Can i get unique id for stack frames use `RtlCaptureContext()`?
2. What about use ebp?

   ```
   unsigned long prev;
   unsigned long addr = 1;
   int eframes = 0;

   __asm { mov prev, ebp };

   while(addr != 0){
       addr = ((unsigned long *)prev)[1]; 
       prev = ((unsigned long *)prev)[0]; 
       stack[eframes] = (void*)addr;
       eframes ++;
   }
   ```

Here the problem when: CRYPTO_function_name() call my malloc(). In process addr == 32768, prev == 2; Exception in next loop. Result as CaptureStackBackTrace(). How to get the previous stack frames?

3. Other quick solutions?